# fill the textboxes with selecting dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to fill textboxes which take data from database. When I select any value using dropdownlist, I need to get ID from dropdownlist and I call a function which fill `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.taskName)`. The page musn't change. How is it possible?

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.jobID, "jobID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("jobID", String.Empty)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.jobID)
</div>
</div>
     <div> @Html.Partial("../Location/taskname") </div>
</div>
```

taskname.cshtml

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.taskName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.taskName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.taskName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a way of at lease including a JavaScript file? If so, then it is possible to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your dropdown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("jobID", null, new {@id="job"})
```

and taskname text box :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.taskName, new {@id="taskname"})
```

do like this, write jquery event for dropdown index change event, and send ajax call to get Task Name against the job Id selected from the dropdown list:

```
$('select#job').change(function(){

var JobId =$(this).val();


// Send Ajax call and get Task name

var Url = 'http://example.com/Controller/Action/?jobid='+JobId ;

$.ajax({
         url:    Url ,
         success: function(result) {
                     $('input#taskname').val(result); 
                  },
         error: function(error) {
                     alert(errorss); 
                  }

    });     


});
```

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("jobID", String.Empty, new {@id="job"})` this line gives error..

Comment: put null in place of String.Empty, it will work then

Comment: oh thanks. ok it's work. and in controller part, I need to result as JSON ?

Comment: yes, you can simply return json result or simple string,its up to you

Comment: alert the response of ajax call to check what is coming

Comment: it's not give error. editor doesn't fill. And I see that I return right value in controller.

Comment: you check whats the response coming in jquery sucess function and error function, put alert in both of them to check its coming in success function or error,

Comment: Pass like this : return JsonResult(value,JsonBehaviour.AllowGet), if you returning string check its going in success or error

Comment: yes. I got right value and `alert` function can show. but editor(textbox) not. it cannot refresh...

Comment: `$("#taskname").val(result);` this not work and editor can't get value. Do I need to do in `form` element ?

Comment: instead of @Html.EditorFor(model => model.taskName) use this:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.taskName, new {@id="taskname"})