# Fill textbox on dropdown selection in mvc entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Asp.net MVC5 and Entity Framework.I am new in Both of technologies.

Basically i create a Form, In this Form a DropDown available, when i select value from DropDown. I want to fill Textboxs which also available on this form.

**This is my Controller**

```
public class ChainController : Controller
{
    private hcEntities db = new hcEntities();

    // GET: Chain
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.name = new SelectList(db.chains,"code","name");
        return View(db.chains.ToList());
    }
}
```

**View:-**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Select Chain
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            @Html.DropDownList("name" , null, new { @class = "form-control" })           
        </div>
    </div>
 @using (@Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Chain UserName
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">            
           @Html.TextBox("ChainName", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) //WHAT DO I DO HERE???????
        </div>
    </div>
 }
</div>
```

**Model(chain.cs generated by EF)**

```
public partial class chain
{
    public long chain_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public long created_by { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_on { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> updated_by { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated_on { get; set; }
    public chain()
    {
        created_by = 1;
        created_on = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I don't know what will be next step. how to fill textbox with value of **Username** from the selection of dropdown.
I find too many answer in stackoverflow but i fill these are not helpful for me. for example
[fill the textboxes with selecting dropdownlist in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563819/fill-the-textboxes-with-selecting-dropdownlist-in-mvc), [How to populate a textbox based on dropdown selection in MVC..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814450/how-to-populate-a-textbox-based-on-dropdown-selection-in-mvc)

Help Me !

Comment: What's the primary key of `chain` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by my self. Here is the solution.

Some change in previous code

**Controller**

Instead of ViewBag, I use ViewData. Both are working perfectly, but i use ViewData

```
    // GET: Chains
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["chain_name"] = new SelectList(db.chains, "code", "name");
        return View(db.chains.ToList());
    }
```

Also i create a function in controller who fetch data from database

```
    //Action Function 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(string code)
    {
        var query = from c in db.chains
                    where c.code == code
                    select c;

        return Json(query);
    }
```

After that I call this Action Controller in my view through javascript.

**View**

```
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Action","chains", FormMethod.Post))
     {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                    Select Chain
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlchainname", (SelectList)ViewData["chain_name"], new {         onchange = "Action(this.value);", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Chain Name
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBox("ChainName", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Username
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBox("username", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Chain Code
       </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBox("ChainCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
     }
```

Javascript Function call by dropdown onChange

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Action(code) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Chains")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { "code": code },
        "success": function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var vdata = data;
                $("#ChainName").val(vdata[0].name);
                $("#ChainCode").val(vdata[0].code);
                $("#username").val(vdata[0].username);
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

That's work Fine...

Comment: something wrong in this code, After Update of Model from database in Entity Framework. Json Data not population into textbox. when i use DeveloperTool i found a error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." Help me for resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You may change your select list parameter from "code" to "username" and use some jQuery code on the view. I have created a simple example for you, please have a look:

In my Controller:

```
List<temp> tempLIst = new List<temp>();
tempLIst.Add(new temp() { Id = 1, code = "111", name = "first", username = "user first" });
tempLIst.Add(new temp() { Id = 1, code = "222", name = "second", username = "user second" });
tempLIst.Add(new temp() { Id = 1, code = "333", name = "third", username = "user third" });
tempLIst.Add(new temp() { Id = 1, code = "444", name = "four", username = "user four" });

ViewBag.name = new SelectList(tempLIst, "username", "name");
return View();
```

Here temp is the class having properties (Id, code, name and username)

In my view

```
<div>
temp list: @Html.DropDownList("name",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.name,"select value")
@Html.TextBox("txtValue")
</div>
```

This is some script section i use on this view page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#name').change(function () {
        $('#txtValue').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now when you run this code snippet, the textbox value will change according to the selected dropdownlist's value.

Comment: thanks subhash,you bind dropdown value as hardcoded but i have to bind dropdown from database.

Comment: Hi @anjyr, replace my tempList with your data list and then check.

In above comment you says that you may have more than 1 textboxes, in this context, you have to do ajax call and return jSon data.
and then assign those values to the respective textboxes..

if you have problem regarding this, please notify me.

Comment: Hi @Subhash, The issue still exists. can you mail me a sample project on my mailid

Comment: Hi @Anjyr, i have checked your profile.
please give me your mailId. 
My MailId: ssprogrammes@gmail.com

Comment: Hi @Subhas My emailid is "Anandrajput007@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

After spending long time on this, I made some new changes in code of @ANJYR - KODEXPRESSION because it has some errors so new changes are as follows:

Changes in Action function of controller:

```
public ActionResult Action(string code)
    {
        var query = from c in db.chains where c.code == code select new { Code = c.code, Name = c.name, UserName = c.username};
        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Changes in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Action(code) {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Chains")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { "code": code },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var vdata = data;
            $("#ChainName").val(vdata[0].Name);
            $("#ChainCode").val(vdata[0].Code);
            $("#username").val(vdata[0].Username);
        }
    }
}); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Since this is a modification of an existing (and accepted) answer, I'd recommend first pointing out the errors on @ANJYR - KODEXPRESSION's code, and giving them an opportunity to update their post. You should also be able to edit their answer to offer minor corrections, assuming they're just typos or syntactical changes. (If your edits are larger, though, you should give the OP the opportunity to update their answer first.)

Comment: my bad...I will defiantly look for it next time for sure..as I am just landed on stackoverflow.. :) BTW there are no minor correction