# Getting Error An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Getting Error after Update data into database

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UpdateChain(Int32, HCIBE.Models.chain)' in 'HCIBE.Controllers.ChainsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.**

**Here is My Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateChain(int? id)
    {
        chain objchain = db.chains.Find(id);
        if (objchain == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(objchain);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateChain(int id, [Bind(Include = "name,code,username,password,updated_by,updated_on")] chain chain)
    {
        chain _objchain = db.chains.Find(id);
        try
        {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _objchain.code = chain.code;
            _objchain.name = chain.name;
            _objchain.username = chain.username;
            _objchain.password = chain.password;
            _objchain.updated_by = Convert.ToInt32("1");
            _objchain.updated_on = DateTime.Now;

            db.Entry(_objchain).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to update data");
        }
        return View(_objchain);
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("UpdateChain", "Chains", FormMethod.Post))
{

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Select Chain
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlchainname", (SelectList)ViewData["chain_name"],"Select Chain", new { onchange = "Action(this.value);", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">
            or @Html.ActionLink("Add New", "Create")

        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Chain Name
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBox("ChainName", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Username
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBox("username", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Chain Code
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBox("ChainCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Password
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.Password("password", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" onclick="UpdateChain()" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateChain(){
        var _vddlChainID = $("#ddlchainname").val();
        alert("Your Selected ID = " + _vddlChainID);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateChain", "Chains")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { "id": _vddlChainID }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Through Dropdown Selection i Fill all textboxes, when i submit form then  i get Error.

**Routing**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Model**

```
public partial class chain
{
    public chain()
    {
        this.templates = new HashSet<template>();
        this.hotels = new HashSet<hotel>();
    }

    public long chain_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public long created_by { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_on { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> updated_by { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated_on { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<template> templates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<hotel> hotels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Care to show your routings? I believe that's the problem. The default route requires an ID.

Comment: You have either omitted some code or not much makes sense here. Why are you using AJAX to post as well as submitting the form at the same time (you are making 2 calls - one passing the id value (AJAX) which does nothing and the other passing `chain` (SUBMIT) without the `id`

Comment: i haven't too much idea about MVC, may be my way of work is wrong so plz. guide me to correct this. thanks

Comment: You have numerous errors. For instance you are rendering a textbox with `name="ChainName" but your model does not include a property with the namae `ChainName` (at least not according to your `[Bind(Include= ...)]` list. Your `[Bind(Include= ...)]` also includes properties for which you are not even rendering a control. But the main issue is your making 2 calls to the controller (the javascript is not neccessary). Please post you model so I can guide you.

Comment: [Bind(Include=.....)] in this context what we pass, Html control name or table column name? i also update my question with model.

Comment: It optional, but yes. If you use it it needs to match the names of your controls which must match the names of you properties (which it currently doesn't), but you should be using a view model in this case. Can you please explain the purpose of the dropdown and what is the script for `onchange = Action(this.value)`

Comment: onchange=Action(this.value) Method call Controller through AJAX to bind all textbox data according to dropdown selection . you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031197/fill-textbox-on-dropdown-selection-in-mvc-entity-framework/26060386#26060386

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62720/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-anjyr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an `object` of `chain` but you have not added value of `id` in it anywhere. You need to set `value` of `id` and add it in `chain object`.

Comment: As id i passing dropdown selectedvalue, so how i pass my dropdown value there. 
@Url.Action("UpdateChain", "Chains",new {id= **DropdownValue** })
i don't know.

Comment: Change this line @Url.Action("UpdateChain", "Chains") to @Url.Action("UpdateChain", "Chains",new {id=_vddlChainID })

Comment: it's not working... The name '_vddlChainID' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: This is not necessary, the `id` value is already passed using `data: { "id": _vddlChainID }`. The problem is 2 calls are being made to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your id is null when you submit the form that's why you are getting this error.

Either specify the the id parameter nullable as you have done in the get method or

store the id in a hidden field to pass it automatically with the model like this

```
@HTML.HiddenFor(Model.id)
```

or pass it manually

```
@HTML.Hidden("id",id)
```

Comment: I don't know how to pass dropdown selected value into any hidden field or any where in view.

Comment: you can directly pass it to the method like this `string ddlchainname` where string is the type of the value being passed by dropdown ddlchainname is the name of the dropdown